# pip fails to install <package> because it always tries to build a failing dependency

Tags: pip, raspberry-pi

I have a pip install problem. pip install  --no-deps seems to always download and try to build a fresh copy of a failing requirement and does not use my fixed and installed local copy. This is on a raspberry pi

For example, the blosc2 package has two bugs on the raspberry pi, which prevent pip from building it. [The bugs are filed as numbers 142 and 143 here `https://github.com/Blosc/python-blosc2/issues/142` ]. I found workarounds and pip built and installed my blosc2 2.2.9

```
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip list -v
Package                Version    Location                                  Installer
---------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------- ---------
arabic-reshaper        3.0.0      /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
astunparse             1.6.3      /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
blosc2                 2.2.9      /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
```

However, when I try to install a package that depends on blosc2 pip still tries to fetch and build a fresh copy of blosc2, which naturally fails and prevents the next package from installing. For example:

```
pip install tables --no-deps
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting tables
  Using cached tables-3.9.1.tar.gz (4.7 MB)
#lines of output omitted

Building wheel for blosc2 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [221 lines of output]
```

How can I get pip to use my installed blosc2 rather than fetching another one?
Thanks
chris